# how to count the num of records in a group in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

For example, I have a table1:

```
+---------------------+
| StartTime           |
+---------------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:56 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:57 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:59 |
+---------------------+
```

tables doesn't have a consecutive time.
For example,it doesn't have

> 2014-04-09 09:47:54,
>   2014-04-09 09:47:58

etc.
Then I use:

```
select count(*),StartTime from this_tables group by StartTime;
```

I get another table2:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| count | StartTime           |
+-------+---------------------+
|     2 | 2014-04-09 09:47:53 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:55 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:56 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:57 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:59 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

But I want get a table3 looks like:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| count | StartTime           |
+-------+---------------------+
|     2 | 2014-04-09 09:47:53 |
|     0 | 2014-04-09 09:47:54 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:55 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:56 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:57 |
|     0 | 2014-04-09 09:47:58 |
|     1 | 2014-04-09 09:47:59 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Table 3 can contain '0' for that StartTime which doesn't exist.
How could I do with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a numbers (tally) table for that. You can create and populate such table (in this case with 100 rows) the following way

```sql
CREATE TABLE tally (n INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
 FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n;
```

*You'll need to have as many rows in this table as the number of seconds in the largest possible interval that you query for.*

Now the query (for the sake of this example for one day 2014-04-09) that you're looking for may look like this

```sql
SELECT b.starttime, COALESCE(count, 0) count
  FROM
(
  SELECT min_dt + INTERVAL n-1 SECOND starttime
    FROM tally t CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT MIN(starttime) min_dt, MAX(starttime) max_dt
      FROM table1
     WHERE starttime >= '2014-04-09'
       AND starttime < '2014-04-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ) i 
   WHERE t.n-1 <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min_dt, max_dt)
) b LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT starttime, COUNT(*) count
    FROM table1
   WHERE starttime >= '2014-04-09'
     AND starttime < '2014-04-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   GROUP BY starttime
) q
    ON b.starttime = q.starttime
```

Output:

```
|                    STARTTIME | COUNT |
|------------------------------|-------|
| April, 09 2014 09:47:53+0000 |     2 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:54+0000 |     0 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:55+0000 |     1 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:56+0000 |     1 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:57+0000 |     1 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:58+0000 |     0 |
| April, 09 2014 09:47:59+0000 |     1 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69eb7/6)** demo

Comment: Actually, my data is about a whole day.So should I make a tally which has 3600*12 rows? I try to revise SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n into SELECT a.N*10 + b.N * 1000 + 1 n,but how to revise it to make it can produces 3600*12 rows?Thank your very much for your time!!!