# how to count the num of records and add them in mysql?(using tally)

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I have a big table with 570000 records, I just select a short part of it as an example.
For example, the table1 is like:

```
+---------------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 08:40:00 | 0.210.243.93  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

The table1 means for each dest IP addr (dIPaddr), it has some network flows,these flows have start time (StartTime).

For IP:`0.210.208.240`, it has 3 flows, but thees flows' time are not consecutive, it has two flows with `09:47:53`, one flow with `09:47:55`,but no `09:47:54`.

For IP:`0.210.243.93`, it has one flow with `08:39:55`,one flow with `08:39:57`, one flow with `08:40:00`, but 0 flow with `08:39:56,08:39:58,08:39:59`.

For IP:`0.210.25.224`, it has 3 flows with `13:02:25`, one flow with `13:02:27`, 0 flow with `13:02:26`.

Now I want to calculate the num of flows with same StartTime,same dIPaddr, and add them up. This means,first, calculate the num of flows with same StartTime,same dIPaddr, get table2:

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       |       count   |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |       2       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:54 | 0.210.208.240 |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:56 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:58 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:59 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:40:00 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |       3       |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:26 | 0.210.25.224  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  |       1       |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

We can see from table2 that for dIPaddr:0.210.208.240, it has(3 records),let's name it table_240:

```
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| StartTime           | dIPaddr       |       count   |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |       2       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:54 | 0.210.208.240 |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |       1       |
```

for dIPaddr 0.210.243.93, it has(6 records),let's name it table_93:

```
| 2014-04-09 08:39:55 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:56 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:57 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:58 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:39:59 | 0.210.243.93  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 08:40:00 | 0.210.243.93  |       1       |
```

for dIPaddr:0.210.25.224, it has,let's name it table_224:

```
| 2014-04-09 13:02:25 | 0.210.25.224  |       3       |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:26 | 0.210.25.224  |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 13:02:27 | 0.210.25.224  |       1       |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Then I want to do : `table_240.count+table_93.count+table_224.count`, 
get a new table called table_final,but in table_final, the num of records should be the minimum num of table_240,table_93 and table_224. Therefore, the table_final should be:

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|     6 |   
|     0 |   
|     3 |
+-------+
(6=2+1+3, 2 is the first record in table_240,1 is the first record in table_93,3 is the first record in table_224.)

(0=0+0+0, 0 is the second record in each of table_240,93,224)

(3=1+1+1, 1 is the third record in each of table_240,93,224)
```

How could I do to get the table_final ?

The above is just a simple example, my table1 have 570000 records, more than 5000 dIPaddr, each dIPaddr have more than 100 flows' records(which means more than 100 records of StartTime).The table_final should hold the minimum num of rows in all these table_dIPaddr.
So the table_final may have 100 rows, or 200 rows,or more, it depends what's the minimum num of rows in these table_dIPaddr(In the above example, table_240, table_93,table_224 belongs to table_dIPaddr.Table_dIPaddr means count the num of rows,group table1 by dIPaddr,StartTime).  Now the situation is that I only have table1, I show table_240 , table_93 etc is just for explaining my need. in table1,there are thousands dIPaddr with more than 100 flows for each dIPaddr. How can I get table_final with table1?

I want to use tally to get table2, I have some hints, but still don't know how to get table2. I think if I want to get table_final, I should get table 2 first, but I don't know how to get table2.  I know how to get table2 if I only have one dIPaddr, but I don't know how to get table2 with different dIPaddr.

This is mysql how to get table2.(some hints)
[how to count the num of records in a group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621386/how-to-count-the-num-of-records-in-a-group-in-mysql)

first, we need create tally:

```
CREATE TABLE tally(n INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);


INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + c.N * 100 + d.N * 1000 + e.N * 10000 + 1 n
FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3     UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) b
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 ) c
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) d
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) e

ORDER BY n;
```

(because one day have 24 hours, so the num of records need larger than 3600*24.)

Then I create a table, which only contains Starttime and dIPaddr for `0.210.208.240`, named this table : temp240, in temp240, it has :

```
 +---------------------+---------------+
 | StartTime           | dIPaddr       |
 +---------------------+---------------+
 | 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
 | 2014-04-09 09:47:53 | 0.210.208.240 |
 | 2014-04-09 09:47:55 | 0.210.208.240 |
 +---------------------+---------------+
```

then create a table called test240,

```
insert into test240
SELECT b.starttime, COALESCE(count, 0) count
 FROM
(
 SELECT min_dt + INTERVAL n-1 SECOND starttime
 FROM tally t CROSS JOIN 
(
SELECT MIN(starttime) min_dt, MAX(starttime) max_dt
  FROM temp240
 WHERE starttime >= '2014-04-09'
   AND starttime < '2014-04-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 ) i 
  WHERE t.n-1 <= TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min_dt, max_dt)
) b LEFT JOIN 
(
 SELECT starttime, COUNT(*) count
FROM temp240
  WHERE starttime >= '2014-04-09'
 AND starttime < '2014-04-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY starttime
) q
  ON b.starttime = q.starttime;
```

Then I get test240:

```
+---------------------+---------------+
| StartTime           |       count   |
+---------------------+---------------+
| 2014-04-09 09:47:53 |       2       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:54 |       0       |
| 2014-04-09 09:47:55 |       1       |
+---------------------+---------------+
```

But I don't know how to get table2, because in reality, table1 contains thousands of dIPaddr, I cannot create thousands tempdIPaddr for each dIPaddr, then get their corresponding testdIPaddr table.I don't know how to revise above mysql to calculate all dIPaddr's.

Comment: in your example you have max 3 rows for the same IP=240 - is it possible that we have 5? 10? what do we do then? the final table must still hold just 3 rows?

Comment: Yes, it is possible have 5 or 10, or more, even thousands. The final table should hold the minimum num of rows of all tables.

Comment: The above is just a simple example, my table1 have 570000 records, more than 5000 dIPaddr, each dIPaddr have more than 100 flows' records.The table_final should hold the minimum num of rows in all these table_dIPaddr. So the table_final may have 100 rows, or 200 rows,or more, it depends what's the minimum num of rows in table_dIPaddr.

Comment: trying to debug your case I found an error in source data :-) you have `2014-04-09 08:39:60` - SQL doesn't accept that time :-) must be `2014-04-09 08:40:00` ;-)

Comment: in your post  you wrote *For IP:0.210.208.240, it has 3 flows, but thees flows' time are not consecutive, it has two flows with 09:47:53, one flow with 09:47:55,but no 09:47:54.*  where this `09:47:54` pop-up from? why do you have new record with this timestamp, if we don't have it in original data? where did you get all those rows with `0` count?

Comment: Sorry, I just give an example, it should be 2014-04-09 08:40:00 ,not 60, I type 60 manually . About "where this 09:47:54 pop-up from? why do you have new record with this timestamp, if we don't have it in original data? ", I can use tally to get the new record, but I just don't know the exact mysql. This is my another question, about how to get new consecutive record by tally,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621386/how-to-count-the-num-of-records-in-a-group-in-mysql

Comment: I want to use tally to get table2, I have some hints, but still don't know how to get table2. I think if I want to get table_final, I should get table 2 first, but I don't know how to get table2.  I know how to get table2 if I only have one dIPaddr, but I don't know how to get table2 with different dIPaddr.

Comment: so, post your query how you've got your `table2`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't put them in different tables for each IP address. Put them all in a single table, grouped by dIPaddr,StartTime.

Make sure this counts table has an auto-increment id field, (say CountRowId), and the count results are entered in order of dIPaddr,StartTime.

Now, further again group by dIPaddr(only) and find the Min and Max of CountRowId values for each dIPaddr.

Add one more column (say OrdinalWithinIP) and for each record, set it to its Max(CountRowId) for dIpaddr MINUS CountRowId. This will give you, for each IPaddr, ordinal numbers for each count record, such as 1, 2, 3 etc.

Then, group by ordinal numbers and sum it up.

Comment: How to make "CountRowId"?

Comment: In MySql, choose the database field of the type as TIMESTAMP and in the "default value" property, put a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.